# Find columns that are one table and but not in the other table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, information-schema

I am working with two very wide tables (Table A, Table B) in Snowflake. Both tables should have exact same columns, though not necessarily in the same order. However Table B is missing a few columns. Is there a way to quickly find all the columns that are in Table A but not in Table B? I am not concerned with the Data, just the existence of columns.

Essentially, I am looking for a SQL way to find all columns in Table that are missing in Table B.

I currently use a ETL tool for this. But it is rather cumbersome. It would be nice if this can be done using SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'tableA'
    AND column_name NOT IN
    (
        SELECT column_name
        FROM information_schema.columns 
        WHERE table_name = 'tableB'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name IN ('tableA', 'tableB')
GROUP BY column_name
HAVING MIN(table_name) = MAX(table_name) AND MIN(table_name) = 'TableA';
```

This is a handy structure that can more easily generalize to multiple tables.  It does assume that the two tables are on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

Below query also gives missing columns in Table B.

```
SELECT column_name  FROM information_schema.columns  WHERE table_name = 'TableA'
MINUS
SELECT column_name  FROM information_schema.columns  WHERE table_name = 'TableB'
```